# Resizing Issue in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, resize

I am new in iOS developing. I am developing an application for portrait and landscape for iPhone.
When i am running app Its running properly in Portrait mode.

But When I change mode from portrait to landscape my view is not going to display proper.

Below I have attached images or portrait mode and landscape mode.!

[portrait mode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wPow.png)

[image: Landscape mode image]

Problem :- There are two button in portrait mode but there are only one button in landscape mode..
I have tried number of combination of resizing. But dont getting proper output.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: u using the autolayout or autoresizing

Comment: if u are using the auto resizing just check through the url one time for reference http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: No.. I have unchecked all... autolayout and autoresizing.

Comment: plz just go through the above link, if it is correct surely work for all orientation, otherwise u will not get the correct answer

Comment: Okkk.. Thanks buddy. I ll. Thanks a lot for ur valuable time.

Comment: @Shreyansh I'm totaly agreed with Anbu.Karthik. You should refer to raywanderlich link. It's best tutorial to guide you how you will deal with autolayout. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all.

I got My answer.
as below

[image]

Also **Uncheck autoresize subview** property of both buttons.